# php condition to filter results from json data

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I am trying to get grand_total result from a database where payment_status = paid please have a look below my database structure and code it's not returning paid status payment results returning all results

**Here is database structure and data**

```
   ref_id |            payment_status          |    grand_total 
     19   |     [{"admin":"","status":"due"}]  |        100
     19   |     [{"admin":"","status":"paid"}] |        50
     19   |     [{"admin":"","status":"paid"}] |        500
```

**Here is my function so far**

```
function total_referral_purchase($referral_id)
{
    $return = 0;
    $sales  = $this->db->get('sale')->result_array();
    foreach ($sales as $row) {
         $payment_status = json_decode($row['payment_status'],true);
         $status = $payment_status['status'];

        if ($row['ref_id'] == $referral_id && $status == 'paid' ) {
            $return += $row['grand_total'];
        }
    }
    return $this->cart->format_number($return);
}
```

**Result I am getting = 0**

**Expected result = 550**

Edit :

```
var_dump array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(20) { 
        ["sale_id"]=> string(3) "202" 
        ["sale_code"]=> string(9) "201906202" 
        ["buyer"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["guest_id"]=> NULL 
        ["ref_id"]=> string(2) "19" 
        ["commission"]=> string(4) "8.83" 
        ["grand_total"]=> string(5) "83.63"
        ["payment_status"]=> string(30) "[{"admin":"","status":"paid"}]" 
        ["payment_details"]=> string(4) "none" 
        ["payment_timestamp"]=> NULL 
        ["sale_datetime"]=> string(10) "1559492618" 
        ["delivary_datetime"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["delivery_status"]=> string(65) "[{"admin":"","status":"pending","comment":"","delivery_time":""}]" 
        ["viewed"]=> string(2) "ok" 
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing looks wrong so far to me, can you `var_dump($sales);` ? and descride what  is the `format_number` function ?

Comment: Can you please debug each line of "total_referral_purchase($referral_id)" function? Verify that "if condition" fulfills your requirement.

Comment: You can also use JSON functions on mysql to avoid the extra code for that it's different from what u asked but might also help you :) 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

Comment: If you add some `var_dump()` in your function, do you get what you need everywhere ? One for the `$referral_id` for example, one for `$sales` and in the foreach loop check `$payment_status`, `$status` and your `$return` before and after the if, check the `$row['ref_id']` too maybe.

Comment: @Frankich => i am getting this result when i did var_dump array(1) { [0]=> array(20) { ["sale_id"]=> string(3) "202" ["sale_code"]=> string(9) "201906202" ["buyer"]=> string(1) "1" ["guest_id"]=> NULL ["ref_id"]=> string(2) "19" ["commission"]=> string(4) "8.83" ["grand_total"]=> string(5) "83.63"

Comment: @Frankich  ["payment_status"]=> string(30) "[{"admin":"","status":"paid"}]" ["payment_details"]=> string(4) "none" ["payment_timestamp"]=> NULL ["sale_datetime"]=> string(10) "1559492618" ["delivary_datetime"]=> string(0) "" ["delivery_status"]=> string(65) "[{"admin":"","status":"pending","comment":"","delivery_time":""}]" ["viewed"]=> string(2) "ok" } } $

Comment: @TroyRoy could you edit instead of comment ? it's not really readable

Comment: @DiarSelimi too advance for me i can't understand this much i am new bee

Comment: @MickaelLeger i wish to get grant_total where ref_id = 1 and payment_status = paid

Comment: @Frankich i have limited controls to add result here in comments better if you answer it and there i will have more format control however you can edit & improve your answer anytime

Comment: @TroyRoy You say you want `ref_id = 1 and payment_status = paid` but in your `var_dump` result you have `ref_id = 19` so it can't works...

Comment: @MickaelLeger i think the main mistake is based on je `json_decode` which return an indexed array from his json format

Comment: @MickaelLeger ref_id = 1 i give just for example the db has too many records 19 also included i have edited my question as per var_dump

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `json_decode` function return an array based on your json format.
So the result of your current code

```
json_decode($row['payment_status'],true);
```

return a array with this format

```
array(1) {
[0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["admin"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["status"]=>
    string(4) "paid"
  }
}
```

because of the '[]' around the json which means it would have multiple record and it parses it as an array.
So the `$status` is always null and should be either be replace by

```
$status = $payment_status[0]['status'];
```

Or change the format from the database like `'{"admin":"","status":"paid"}'` to work in your current way.

Answer (score 3):

The JSON that you are using is an array, as indicated by the square brackets.

There are two ways to fix this:

1. You change the JSON from `[{"admin":"","status":"due"}]` to `{"admin":"","status":"due"}` in your database. This makes it a single JSON object instead of an array.
2. Instead of `$status = $payment_status['status'];` use `$status = $payment_status[0]['status'];` This selects the value of 'status' from the first object in the array.